# Keeping a data table in session for current user

Tags: loops, session, datatables

I have a C# .net 4.5 website where users select certain data fields and then they get generated and the user can download the data.

There is a new feature management wants me to add that will allow users to select any field even if there are fields that do not go together and when the user submits this job I have to split out the fields and generate however many jobs it takes to create them.

Without having to change my entire back end process I wanted to store the users selections in a data table in memory and when they submit I can loop through the table and submit the jobs accordingly.

What would be the best way to have a data table that will be alive during the entire user session?  Should I create it as a session variable?  The user can come back and add or remove from it at anytime while on the site.

Thank you

Comment: possibly options are sessionstate, cookie, database. How long do you want to maintain user selection

Comment: Thanks lordkain,  I need to keep it until the user leaves the website or selects to generate his data.  The data table would cleared after the data is generated.   I want to try and use the best solution so it doesn't cause a slow down on the site.    That's why I didn't want to use a database because there would be constant calls being made.  I figured to hold the data within memory for each user and when they decide to create the data I would put it all into the database with one call.  Thanks